# Storing data on Arduino

Tags: database, arduino

I'm building a sketch for an Arduino Mega 2560 with Ethernet Shield (and SD Port included). 
The sketch will need to work with a couple of data tupels like:

```
Key1 Value1
Key2 Value2
etc.
```

This "database" is extended, when the sketch is running and some tupels have to be read. The data should be available, after rebooting, too. The EEPROM has only 4 KB, that will be to less.

What is a good way of storing the data? How can I access them easily? 
I found http://blog.brauingenieur.de/2014/01/20/extended-database-library-using-an-sd-card/ But it seems, that I have to say how many records should be stored? But this must be flexible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the mentioned library, you doesn't need to specify the number of records. Just call the **appendRec** method.

if you check the source code you'll see that it will append the record to the end of record set

```
// Adds a record to the end of the record set.
// This is the fastest way to add a record.
EDB_Status EDB::appendRec(EDB_Rec rec)
{
  if (EDB_head.n_recs + 1 > limit()) return EDB_TABLE_FULL;
  EDB_head.n_recs++;
  writeRec(EDB_head.n_recs,rec);
  writeHead();
  return EDB_OK;
}
```

On your refereced example the author only specifies the number of entries because he wants to loop over his data. But the real magic occurs with the method **appendRec**